# Removing blank rows from end of CSV file in excel, or Step through macro using variable steps?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet that strings together lots of information if applicable and a tab that then uses the aggregate function to put all this information in one list.

I then have the below code which originally was built with the help of people on here to work through and create csv files for each dim rowsinfile.

When creating the sheet I thought this would work, but after building it out a bit more the length of data can vary, and the number of rows needed for each csv file can vary, so for example I could have a tab that has 6 rows of data that needs to be made into one csv file, or that has 100 rows of data that needs to be made into 8 csv files.

Originally I thought I would just space the data to the worst case, say 30 rows and have the macro create the csv file like this, but the program I need to upload the csv files into will not work if there are blank rows at the end of the csv.

So... I either need a way of removing the blank rows at the end of each csv, which when used range is alot bigger than the number of rows that have data in (because of the number of cells that will need to have the aggregate formula in, and even if I wrap the aggregate in "if result = nothing then "" " the csv still sees the cell with "" in as a row)

Or

I need a way to change my code so it steps through creating seperate csv files based on a series of variables, ie create a csv file with 6 rows (I can get this number from a cell as per my latest code below) but cannot work out how to then step through and change this reference number to another cell at each pass?

I am sure the stepping through at variable lengths option is easier, but I lack the skills myself to work it out.

Thank you!!

```
'resets used range to try and stop creating blank csv files
a = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ThisSheet As Worksheet
Dim NumOfColumns As Integer
Dim RangeToCopy As Range
Dim WorkbookCounter As Integer
Dim RowsInFile


Application.ScreenUpdating = True


'Initialize data
Set ThisSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
NumOfColumns = 1
WorkbookCounter = 1
RowsInFile = Sheets("Upload").Cells(1, 4).Value     '10     'how many rows (incl. header) in new files?

For p = 1 To ThisSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count Step RowsInFile

    'Paste the chunk of rows for this file
    Set RangeToCopy = ThisSheet.Range(ThisSheet.Cells(p, 1), ThisSheet.Cells(p + RowsInFile - 1, NumOfColumns))


    xName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Files for upload testing\" & "Purchase" & Format(Now(), "yyyymmddhhmmss") & ".csv"

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))



    Open xName For Output As #1
    For Each xRow In RangeToCopy.Rows


        xStr = ""
      For Each xCell In xRow.Cells
           xStr = xStr & xCell.Value & Chr(9)
        Next
        While Right(xStr, 1) = Chr(9)
            xStr = Left(xStr, Len(xStr) - 1)
        Wend
        Print #1, xStr


    Next

    Close #1

    'Increment file counter
    WorkbookCounter = WorkbookCounter + 1
Next p

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Set wb = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't quite work out how many columns you are trying to copy or if this is varying.

But rather than trying to remove the blank lines, just don't write them.

This isn't the best way of doing this but will work with your code.

```
For Each xRow In RangeToCopy.Rows
    Dim writeThisLine As Boolean
    writeThisLine = False
    xStr = ""
    For Each xcell In xRow.Cells
        If xcell.Text <> "" Then writeThisLine = True
        xStr = xStr & xcell.Value & Chr(9)
    Next
    While Right(xStr, 1) = Chr(9)
        xStr = Left(xStr, Len(xStr) - 1)
    Wend
    If writeThisLine Then Print #1, xStr
Next
```

Comment: Thanks Gareth. The data I am trying to create a csv for will be 1 column only. I played around loads with trying to remove the lines with "" in but could never get it to work. Let me have a play with the code you have provided. Am I right in thinking the code you have provided replaces the code I have at "For each xRow" onwards?

Comment: Yes.  I assume you copied the code as it is trying to span across the columns, but it should still work.